# Software to recover deleted Files from a Specific Folder

Tags: windows-7

I am searching for a software which can recover deleted Files from a Specific Folder. The software should work not just with standard file types like images, videos and other. I already tried AnyRecover, but it didn´t help. So I am searching for a similar software, where you can just select a specific folder to search and not whole HD.

Comment: You can't recover from a specific folder unless you have some sort of journaling/history, because the path information isn't a part of the file & so once deleted is no longer associated with the file. Unless partial directory information can be found, you will often not even get the file name.

Comment: @Tetsujin AnyRecover can at least find deleted files from some folder, but the problem there seems to be restoring the files.

Comment: If it can see a path, the the directory wasn't destroyed at that point. If it can't recover them, then the files were overwirtten & you need to go 'down a level' to recover - that would be directory & name info gone.

Comment: @Tetsujin no directory wasn destroyed, just 1 file there was deleted by accident. Now just need to restore exactly that 1 file.

Answer (score 2):

For years now, my go-to has been [Recouva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva).

I have tried others, but keep coming back. Try it. It's free and does the job extremely well

Comment: Sorry, but does it recover files from a single folder or complete HD?

Comment: Your choice.  Just

Comment: So explicite from some selected single folder is also posible?

Comment: Yes. You can recover explicitly form a single folder. Up to you if you make that folder "c:\ ", but you an also make it "C:\my\secret\folder". Please accept my apologies if my answers are a little sort these few days, but life things are happening. Try it; you won't regret it.

Comment: OK then I try it.

Comment: If you like it, please let us know, because that would help other people who read your question in future

Comment: Unfortunatelly the program is not even able to find the deleted file.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that.  Perhaps look at [https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=AnyRecover](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=AnyRecover) ?  Depending on how much you value your data, you may have to pay for professional recovery. until then, do NOT access that drive. And, if the drive is C:, then don't use your PC.